# Add new object in {} to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, grouping

I want to edit my code to add {} new object to my array grouping by id , my code add object to my old object : 
my code and result are:

```js
result = {
  "field": [{
    "id": "11",
    "name": "name",
    "email": "email"
  }, {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "name",
    "email": "email"
  }, {
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "name",
    "email": "email"
  }]
}
results = result.field;
groups = {};
for (var i in results) {
  var groupName = results[i].id;
  if (!groups[results[i].id]) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
  }
  groups[groupName].push(results[i].name);
  groups[groupName].push(results[i].email);
}
console.log(groups);
```

I want the result be like this :

```
 {"1234": [
        {"name" : "name",
        "email":"email"},
        {"name":"name",
        "email":"email"}],
     "11":[{"name":"name",
        "email":"email"}]}
```

** I use wso2 so I cannot use any method like : reduce .
Thanks ..

Comment: Expected result is invalid JSON.

Comment: You wrote {"name", "email"} but maybe you meant ["name", "email"] ?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks I forgot {} , the valid json is {"1234": [
        {"name" : "name",
        "email":"email"},
        {"name":"name",
        "email":"email"}],
     "11":[{"name":"name",
        "email":"email"}]}

Comment: @Bemmu thanks I forgot {} the valid one is : {"1234": [
        {"name" : "name",
        "email":"email"},
        {"name":"name",
        "email":"email"}],
     "11":[{"name":"name",
        "email":"email"}]}

Comment: Please update your question. Also: format and indent your code properly. It's almost impossible to read.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thank you robby I edit my post , hope it's clear ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it finally , the answer is :

```js
result = {
  "field": [{
    "id": "11",
    "name": "asma",
    "email": "asma@hotmail"
  }, {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "jone",
    "email": "jone@hotmail"
  }, {
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "jak",
    "email": "jak@hotmail"
  }]
}
results = result.field;
groups = {};
for (var i in results) {
  var groupName = results[i].id;
  if (!groups[results[i].id]) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
  }
 groups[groupName].push({"name" :results[i].name,"email":results[i].email})
}
console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make use of `reduce()` method:

```js
var object = { "field": [  {"id":"11","name":"name","email":"email"},{"id":"11","name":"name","email":"email"},{"id":"1234","name":"name","email":"email"}]};

var result = object.field.reduce((acc, {id, ...rest})=>{
    acc[id] = acc[id] || [];
    acc[id].push({...rest});
    return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks but I use wso2 , so, I cannot use any methods , for that I write it like this , I need just add new object in {} under the same id ..

Comment: @AsmaAlghamdi, This is something, you should have mentioned in the question itself.